# how to make two grids with master detail relationship in struts2 jquery having functionality add, edit and delete any record from any grid?

Tags: java, struts2, jqgrid

I have the requirement of 2 jQuery grid having interlinked within them using Mastr - Details Relationship.
In Both grid user can enter the records and can retrive data in case od searched records.
Any idea or sample code expected.

Thanks in Advance